# How effective is *accio*?

Tags: harry-potter, spells

So, in the books we see the spell *accio* being used a few times to bring forth a desired object to the caster. However, we also see that to get the desired effect, one doesn't have to be too accurate in their description of the object (Harry says *accio firebolt* and his broom alone comes to him), and yet sometimes they get a range of objects that fit the description (Hermione calls for books about Horcruxes, and many of them come to her).

So I think that begs two questions.

1. What is the range of *Accio*? Could I call for something that was on the other side of the country? What about the other side of Hogwarts?
2. How accurate is it? If I said "Accio Notebook" would it bring me my own notebook, or all the notebooks in the room?

Comment: * *Accio duplicate!* * :-)

Comment: @Richard fair enough. It didn't show up as I was looking for it.

Comment: I've added a smiley in case you thought I was chiding you.